# MSIE9 -- text in input/textarea not obeying current padding when CSS for width and padding adjusted simultaneously

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have a simple script that adds and removes `padding-left` to textareas/inputs on `focus`/`blur`, respectively. This is to make room for a small, absolutely-positioned button on the left side of the field, without blocking the text underneath it. [Edit] It simultaneously changes the width of the element as well, to keep the total size of the block consistent.

In almost all browsers this works fine and dandy, except MSIE 9. [Edit] Although the box stays the same size, indicating the CSS for both properties was properly updated, the text in the input/textarea behaves as though the padding has not changed. I know the callbacks for the `focus`/`blur` events are firing and updating the DOM object's style properties properly, because fetching the current value of the property always gives you the value expected.

i.e.

```
var field = $(field);
field.css({
  'padding-left' : 0
});
console.log(field.css('padding-left')); // '0px'
```

Yet the text in the input/textarea field still shows the previous padding. Basically, something seems to be confusing MSIE9's rendering engine in the context these fields appear when you try to change width and padding at the same time.

As soon as you start typing in the field MSIE will fix the problem and make the text in the input/textarea obey the current padding. Realizing this, I tried adding a `field.val(field.val());` to the end of the `blur` and `focus` callbacks. This solves one problem, and introduces another in the form of resetting the caret position to the beginning of the input/textarea.

Is there any way to force a browser to redraw a given element without going through the drama of removing and reinserting it into the DOM?

[EDIT]

Here is a fiddle showing an abbreviated form of the code (which has additional functionality in its actual context):

http://jsfiddle.net/KYrXM/

You will see that the padding is updated, but no visible change is made until AFTER you start typing.

This problem goes away if I choose not to change the width property as well, though I need to in order to keep the box size constant in my application.

Comment: What about `field[0].style.paddingLeft = "0px";`? (Assuming `field` is a jQuery object. If not, get rid of the `[0]`)

Comment: Why don't you change the width instead of the padding?

Comment: Where is the HTML? Can we see a demo?

Comment: Can you insert and remove the button as well as changing the padding?

Comment: *... something seems to be confusing MSIE9 ...* **+1**

Comment: It actually works fine for me in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/YNFrZ/ I think we need to see your code, and you may be asking the wrong question here... do you want to solve the real problem you have?

Comment: However, if it is a repaint issue, how about `var p = field.parent(), next = field.next(); field.detach(); if(next.length) field.before(next); else field.appendTo(p);`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KYrXM/ is a fiddle showing the problem. It is an abbreviated form of the actual code, which has additional functionality. However, testing the fiddle in IE9 shows the same problem.

Comment: @WesleyMurch -- your code works fine in IE9. It seems to be the fact that I am also changing the width property at the same time. If you go to my fiddle in IE9 you will see the padding is visibly changed, but ONLY after you type in the field.

Comment: Did you mean to have the CSS Normalization script on (see the checkbox on the left below the frameworks)? When I remove that checkmark (http://jsfiddle.net/KYrXM/1/), I *think* it fixes the IE9 problem, although I'm not sure what you're after...? (Although oddly now the `textarea` seems to squinch up just slightly when focused.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish No, I didn't mean to have that checked. Unchecking it only fixes the problem for the initial focus. The first blur will fail to move the text back even though the padding is now 0.

Comment: Oh right. I didn't notice that. This seems so familiar for some reason; there's an issue I can't quite put my finger on. Have you considered [`contenteditable` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_Editable)? Not to discourage continuing the question, but `contenteditable` is much more useful and would be a boon to what you're trying to do, I think.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I didn't know about `contenteditable`. That's pretty cool stuff. Unfortunately, for this project I have to fly pretty narrowly within the constraints of an existing, extensive forms framework dating back 15 years. ;)

Comment: That's too bad too, because this works perfectly in IE7, 8 and 9: http://jsfiddle.net/KYrXM/3/ And I barely changed anything.

Comment: Probably the problem is not your code but IE. I want to suggest to test it in IE10. If the problem is not there it is a problem of IE9. Don't try to fix that error in IE. Also users can use another browser to use your page. IE is still there but no longer one the major ones, don't waste time if it is not worth it.

Comment: @Erwinus - While I would like to believe that, there's a bit of wistful [sic] thinking there. I'm surprised at the number of non-savvy country folk who have somehow adapted to using Firefox or Chrome (usually for some singular reason they can't quite elucidate), but they *all* still use IE for some things. A very nice lady I know uses Chrome to Google, IE to work (including things that need to run ActiveX) and to "read the news" (ie, her MSN.com homepage). Even if fewer (by half) people still think *It's the INTERNET!!!*, it's still very much in play, especially in corporate environments.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: I know the problem you discribe but is a problem from the past. When you look at worldwide statistics IE is historically low. You have to convince your customers that IE is no longer a major brand (sort of, not required, not dominating) to surf the internet. Show them some statistics. Sounds a bit sick to you, I know, but you can't support all mistakes MS made any longer and there is a good reason for it..... (see next message below)......

Comment: It is not your problem but a problem of MS, you can use another browser when it is not working correctly. Don't waste your time when it is too difficult, blame MS not yourself. Show them the difference and when they want to have fixed it, ask some extra fee. I do this with my customers for about a year and with success. The only thing you have to do is showing them the differences. I have made some W3C pages to do that. For IE7, IE8 and IE9. In all other browsers they look fine but only in IE there some things that doesn't show up or are showed incorrectly. Show it and they see the differenc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why this is; definitely a bug in IE9, but if you instead set the padding to an empty string `''` instead of `'0px'`, it works.

```
field.css({
  'padding-left' : '' // <- Use '' instead of 0.
});
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KYrXM/4/

Alternatively, it will also work if you set it to `1` instead of `0`, and you could probably program around the extra pixel.

Comment: FYI for future reference to SO-goers: animating over those two properties instead of changing them outright with the `.css()` method also bypasses this bug (though wasn't appropriate for my application).

Comment: Silly IE, takes hours to find it without the possibility to ask MS for a fee to solve the bug. It is a bug!

Answer (score 0):

This forces redraw and fixes the problem (but it's an ugly hack though):

```
$('#your-input-element').replaceWith($('#your-input-element').clone());
```